# Rendering only the <form> tag

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is there any way that i can render ONLY the start `<form>` tag of a Zend_Form object?

```
print $this->registerForm->renderForm();
```

renders `<form></form>`, and i only need `<form>`

Edit:

After Asleys possible solution i wrote this for My_Form class

```
public function renderFormOpen() {
    return str_replace('</form>', '', $this->renderForm());
}

public function renderFormClose() {
    return '</form>';
}
```

Still looking for at ZF way of doing thins, even though i don't think there is any - after going through the code in the ZF library.

Comment: I have to ask. Why? If you want to use custom stuff in your form you could always implement a viewhelper.

Comment: I know i could implement viewhelpers for custom elements and such.. My problem being want add a list of products, each products have a input field for 'quantity'. The amount of products is changing as they are pulled from a DB-table. And also the presentation of the products would be too overkill byilding custom decorators for just that. And also i would like to put the productlisting inside a 'box' that utilizes sliding doors teqniue, thus containing multiple div tags. I allready have a view-helper set up to output such box, but from view directly not from form.

Comment: Why not just create the fields dynamicaly inside your form object? You know, just loop thru the db entries and create corresponding zend_form_element.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as i wrote, the way that i want to present the products to the customer would take great amount of hours just to write the decorators and get them to work like desired. Zend_Form is great, but also a bit stiff, you really need to know the inner workings of it. I think it's the hardest part of ZF to work with. Well.. i might just hardcode the <form> tags into the viewscript and just render the displayGrooups.

Comment: Easy way, just do a string replace on it

Comment: Hmm.. actually sounds like a good idea, the </form> part will never change, but the <form> potentially could. So my solution hardcoding the <form> tag and using $form->getAction() ..->getMethod() and so on, is not utilizing the Zend_Form in the best possible way. By using string replacement, i can utilize the Zend_Form to customise the form tag. Anyways, a good solution. My question was actually pointed at finding a ZF way of disabling the </form> tag. I have scourged the Form Decorator, and theres no logic in it that disable it. Thought there maybe was openOnly switch, like other decorators.

Comment: @Iznogood: I actually took up your solutions too. Adding all products to the form, I also add it to the row (I have a custom Row class that supports this). Then in the view when printing the products i also print $row->formElement. This way i get a nice and clean way of adding elements to the form and print them out. It's also possible to use $form->getElement('product'.$row->id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* write an custom form-decorator that uses a custom view-helper that only renders the open form tag. But I think this would be overkill.
Just "hardcode" the form-tags and fill the attributes with the data provided by the form-variable in your view.

```
<!--in your view-template -->
<form action="<?php echo $this->form->getAction() ?>"
      enctype="<?php echo $this->form->getEnctype() ?>"
      method="<?php echo $this->form->getMethod() ?>"
      id="<?php echo $this->form->getId() ?>"
      class="<?php echo $this->form->getAttrib('class') ?>" >

    <!--in case your products are represented as elements -->
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getElements() as $element): ?>
       <?php echo $element ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <!--in case your products are represented as displayGroups -->
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getDisplayGroups() as $displayGroup): ?>
       <?php echo $displayGroup ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <!--in case your products are represented as subforms -->
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getSubforms() as $subform): ?>
       <?php echo $subform ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <!--in case your products are rendered by a view helper -->
    <?php foreach ($this->products as $product): ?>
       <?php echo $this->renderProduct($product) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Just for fun the overkill way

```
// Get your products form
$form = new Form_Products();
// Add custom prefix path
$form->addPrefixPath('Foobar_Form_Decorator', 'Foobar/Form/Decorator', 'decorator');
// Set OnlyOpenTagForm-ViewHelper for FormDecorator
$form->getDecorator('Form')->setHelper('OnlyOpenTagForm');

// copy Zend/View/Helper/Form to Foobar/Form/Decorato/OnlyOpenTagForm.php
// In OnlyOpenTagForm.php
//   replace Zend_View_Helper_Form with Foobar_View_Helper_OnlyOpenTagForm
//   replace method "form" with onlyOpenTagForm"
//   replace
if (false !== $content) {
    $xhtml .= $content
           .  '</form>';
}
//   with:        
if (false !== $content) {
    $xhtml .= $content;
}
```

Done! - The Java-Guys will love it ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can render just the open form tag by passing false to the form decorator like so:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderForm(false) ?>
```

Which will output something like:

```
<form id="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/post">
```

Additonally you can pass a string to the form decorator to be enclosed by the form tags like so:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderForm('Some Text') ?>
```

Which outputs something like:

```
<form id="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/simchas/post">Some Text</form>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: RenderForm(false) does not work anymore with the latest versions of ZF.

Comment: Worked for me with version 1.9.5

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
echo $this->form->getDecorator('Form')->setElement($this->form)->render(false);
```